# Can we say "I early came" or "I, early, came" like "I, hardly, know you"?

Tags: sentence-structure

I can understand that 'hardly' was put soon after 'I' to give stress on the adverb.

Why does it feel incorrect if someone says, "I early came" or "I, early, came".

It seems some people often use "I, early, came to know about you". This seems correct.

"I, early, came here" - This seems wrong.

I feel like I understand why. But I can not put it into an explanatory form.

It was my colleague who once said "I early came". And he **frequently** uses poor sentence structure. He is not at all used to English.  So, is there any way I can explain to him how to place adverbs correctly and also how to avoid mistakes like this (if it is, in fact, a mistake)?

Answer (score 2):

Each type of adverb generally has a preferred position, but under some circumstances other positions are valid. This [link](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adverbs-and-adverb-phrases-position) gives some guidance about adverb position.

**Early** is an adverb of time: the preferred position is at the end, but it is also possible to put the adverb at the beginning. **early** doesn't seem right in this position, but **earlier** or **early this morning** sound OK.

> I came early
>
> Earlier, I came and there was a band playing
>
> Early this morning, the birds were singing

**Hardly** is an adverb of degree, which generally goes in the middle position- between the subject and verb:

> I hardly know you

Comment: So, no need to put comma here? - "I, hardly, know you"

Comment: If you put the adverb in the preferred position, no comma is necessary. Sometimes people add commas if they put it in an unusual position.